# realizar dos sentencias en MYSQL

Tags: mysql

me gustaria saber si se puede realizar dos sentencias en mysql en una misma linea de codigo o como seria la forma correcta

lo que busco es dropear una tabla y la otra sentencia seria delete para borrar un registro en especifico.

se como realizar cada una de esas sentencias problemas pero repito quiero saber como puedo unir ambas y que no haya problema.

ya he intentado de varias maneras pero no puedo me tirar error
es para una pagina web.

Comment: si haces un `DROP` de una tabla entonces la eliminas, si haces un `DELETE` entonces solo eliminas un registro, pero si ya has borrado la tabla entonces ya no se puede, aclara por favor ¿la tabla es la misma, son instrucciones a tablas distintas?

Comment: delete en una tabla

Comment: drop en otra tabla, completamente distintas

Comment: podrías agregar lo que hayas intentado por favor?

Comment: no se donde deje el codigo :( lo mencione en la publicación porque si intente

Comment: encuentra lo por favor y agrégalo, será necesario para mantener tu pregunta abierta

Answer (score 2):

En mysql tienes la claúsula UNION que se utiliza para combinar 2 consultas select en una misma sentencia

```
SELECT nombre FROM tabla1 UNION SELECT id FROM      
tabla2
```

Pero si lo que quieres es borrar una tabla y luego un registro de otra tabla puedes ejecutar las 2 sentencias en una misma instrucción separándolas

```
DROP TABLE ejemplo; DELETE FROM ejemplo2 WHERE   
id='1'
```